# Из БД не выводятся таблицы с id > 10

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу данные из таблицы таким образом: (фаил Function.php)

```
function get_tests(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE enable = '1'";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if(!$res) return false;
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
* получение данных теста
**/
function get_test_data($test_id){
    if( !$test_id ) return;
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT q.question, q.parent_test, a.id, a.answer, a.parent_question, q.correct_answer
        FROM questions q
        LEFT JOIN  answers a
            ON q.id = a.parent_question
        LEFT JOIN test
            ON test.id = q.parent_test
                WHERE q.parent_test = $test_id AND test.enable = '1'
                ORDER BY rand()
";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $query,);
    $data = null;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        if( !$row['parent_question'] ) return false;
        $data[$row['parent_question']][0] = $row['question'];
        $data[$row['parent_question']][1] = "0%";
        $data[$row['parent_question']][2] = "25%";
        $data[$row['parent_question']][3] = "50%";
        $data[$row['parent_question']][4] = "75%";
        $data[$row['parent_question']][5] = "100%";
        $data[$row['parent_question']]["correct_answer"] = $row[ 'correct_answer'];
    }
    return $data;
}

    function get_correct_answers($test) {
        if( !$test ) return false;
        global $db;
        $query = "SELECT q.id AS question_id, a.id AS answer_id, q.correct_answer
            FROM questions q
            LEFT JOIN answers a
                ON q.id = a.parent_question
            LEFT JOIN test
                ON test.id = q.parent_test
                    WHERE q.parent_test = $test AND a.correct_answer = '1' AND test.enable = '1'";
        $res = mysqli_query ($db, $query);
        $data = null;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $data[$row['question_id']] = $row['correct_answer'];
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Добавляю в БД записи (Через phpMyAdmin):

```
INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `question`, `parent_test`, `correct_answer`) VALUES
(1, 'Первая', 1, 1),
(2, 'Вторая', 1, 1),
(3, 'Третья', 1, 1),
(4, 'Четвертая', 1, 1),
(5, 'Пятая', 1, 1),
(6, 'Шестая', 1, 1),
(7, 'Седьмая', 1, 1),
(8, 'Восьмая', 1, 1),
(9, 'Девятая', 1, 1),
(10, 'Десятая', 1, 1),
(11, 'Одинадцатая', 1, 1);
```

Вывожу в индексном файле:

```
<?php print_arr($test_data) ?>
```

В ответ получаю пустоту, **НО** если убираю 11 пункт - получаю:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Вторая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Пятая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Третья
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Шестая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Десятая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Первая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Девятая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Четвертая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Седьмая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Восьмая
            [1] => 0%
            [2] => 25%
            [3] => 50%
            [4] => 75%
            [5] => 100%
            [correct_answer] => 1
        )

)
```

Если **ID** записи **до 10** *(включительно)* - всё выводится, но если появляется **11** - **var_damp** ничего не возвращает.
То есть, если **ID** пишу любой выше **10** - ничего не возвращается.

Структура `ID - int(10) UNSIGNED AI`

P.S.
Гуглил уже всё, что можно. Такое ощущение сложилось, что подобной ошибки ни у кого не бывает.

Comment: Ну раз ни у кого не бывает, то приводи тогда в своем вопросе полное тестовое окружение: РНР код, который создает таблицу, записывает в неё 11 записей, и пытается вывести.

Comment: @Ипатьев
В таблице уже существует 10 записей. Всё работает. Добавляю еще одну или меняю ID - на 11 (или больше) - возвращает пустоту.

Comment: Вот и прекрасненько. Осталось это продемонстрировать на конкретном примере. Действуй.

Comment: @Ипатьев Изменил вопрос. Весь фаил function.php

Comment: *`$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE enable = '1'";`* - вот что, реально поле `enable` имеет строковый тип?

Comment: нет-нет. не надо "менять вопрос". Ты уж добей свой старый, и убедись, что в твоей постановке, *разумеется*, это полная бессмыслица. а то началось - "ой, у меня тут джойн", потом начнется "ой я не в ту базу посмотрел". Нет уж, какой вопрос задал - тот и продолжай. Давай, не "function.php", а тот код про который я тбебе сразу написал: создание таблицы, добавление 11 записей, вывод.

Comment: @Akina а что, это реально имеет какое-то значение или отношение к вопросу?

Comment: @Akina да (на всякий случай проверил).

Comment: @Ипатьев всё сделал, как Вы сказали. Обновил вопрос - весь код, после воспроизведения привел!

Comment: я не могу его выполнить. Вопрос не в том, что ты там у себя исполняешь, а в том чтобы был **изолированный воспроизводимый** пример: **создание таблицы** (у тебя нет), заполнение таблицы (есть), вывод из **этой** таблицы (у тебя нет)

Comment: а то у тебя прямо как в анекдоте, "у таракана уши в ногах". Ты что-то делаешь, смотришь на результат, и делаешь какой-то случайный вывод, который ни к реальности, ни к твоему коду не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @Ипатьев - спасибо за проявленный интерес к решению моего вопроса. А касаемо советов по выкладке кода - учту в дальнейшем.

Comment: Это на самом деле совет не по выкладке кода, а по подходу к решению проблем. У тебя сложная система, ты делаешь поверхностный вывод о её работе. Это не очень продуктивно, но в принципе нормально. Но только если ты сразу **проверяешь** свою догадку.  Сделал тестовый код, проверил, убедился, что вывод из **одной** таблицы работает как надо - начал думать **в чём ещё** может быть проблема. Наверное, в запросе. Окей, запускаешь этот запрос. **БЕЗ** РНР кода. Убеждаешься, что дело в нём. И уже с этим запросом приходишь сюда, и задаёшь осмысленный вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев - я понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из запросов из кода:

```sql
SELECT q.id AS question_id, a.id AS answer_id, q.correct_answer
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.parent_question
LEFT JOIN test ON test.id = q.parent_test
WHERE q.parent_test = $test AND a.correct_answer = '1' AND test.enable = '1'
```

Запрос - неверный. Он превращает LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN - следует ли удивляться, что результат далёк от желаемого?

Должно быть

```sql
SELECT q.id AS question_id, a.id AS answer_id, q.correct_answer
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON q.id = a.parent_question AND a.correct_answer = '1'
LEFT JOIN test ON test.id = q.parent_test AND test.enable = '1'
WHERE q.parent_test = $test
```

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитав Ваши правки - увидел в чем была ошибка.
У меня в БД - существует Таблица Answers - в которой ответы на вопросы - и при их отсутствии - ничего не выводится.
Спасибо большое!